# Question about powers

Tags: exponentiation

I've been trying to solve this problem, but I can't do it by any means other than brute force, I need help, please. The result is: 6,000.00001

$$\frac{1}{10^{-3}}+\frac{10^2}{2\cdot 10^{-2}}+\frac{10^{-4}}{10}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{10^{-3}} = \frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{10^3}} = 10^3 = 1000$$

$$\frac{10^2}{2*10^{-2}} = \frac{10^4}{2} = 5*10^3 = 5000$$

$$\frac{10^{-4}}{10} = 10^{-5} = \frac{1}{10^5} = 0.00001$$

If we add this 3 numbers we'll end up with 6 000.00001.